# Making this code multithreaded?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I've made this quick piece of code as a test, but it's actually something I've been wondering for a while. How do I make code multithreaded? I've read a bunch of tutorials and got some things to work parallel with each other, but what I'm missing is the ability to have a pool of workers go through a big list and do some work on the items. Once a worker is done it should start on the next available job. The code I'm currently trying to make work is this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import sys

f = open("premiumPlayers.txt", "a")
usernames = open("players.txt").read().splitlines()

for index, value in enumerate(usernames):
    try:
        url = "https://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=" + value
        html = str(urlopen(url).read())
        if ("true" in html):
            f.write(value + "\n")
            print(str(index) + "/" + str(len(usernames)) + " Added " + value)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
```

It's a simple Minecraft username checker, but if you have a list of over 20,000 usernames it takes a long time with just a single thread. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need [Threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I tried Googling it, but nothing came up.

Comment: Ah, it didn't show up as a link before. Thank you, I'll check it out.

Comment: While I'm reading up on Threading, I would be happy if anyone could give me an example of what it might look like using my code.